# show that $a^2-1$ is a quadratic nonresidue mod $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 6\pmod 7$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

**Question**: Let prime number $p>7$, for  positive integer $a,b,c$ such $1<a<b<c<p$, and
$$a+b+c\equiv a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv a^5+b^5+c^5\equiv\frac{p-1}{2}\pmod p$$

show that:
$a^2-1$ is a quadratic nonresidue mod $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 6\pmod 7$

I think following identity can work?

> $$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$
>   and
>   $$a^5+b^5+c^5=(a+b+c)^5-5(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ac)$$

Comment: Source of the question, please?

Comment: a frend creat it,and  I can't solve it

Comment: So, why not ask your friend how to solve it?

Comment: he can't tell me his answer

Comment: Doesn't sound very friendly to me.

Comment: One gets $ab+bc+ca \equiv -1/2 \pmod p$ and $abc \equiv 1/8 \pmod p$.

Comment: Do you have any examples of triples $(a,b,c)$ that satisfy the rather stringent-looking conditions?

Comment: @BarryCipra, $(a,b,c,p)=(4,5,10,13)$.

Comment: Also, $(9,16,18,29)$

Answer (score 5):

Since $ab+bc+ac$ and $abc$ are rational fractions in $a+b+c,a^3+b^3+c^3,a^5+b^5+c^5$,
you can show that for $p \neq 2,3$, then $a,b,c$ satisfy these relations mod $p$ if and only if they are roots of a certain cubic equation.
(in fact, you get the equation $8a^3+4a^2-4a-1 = 0$)

It turns out that over $\Bbb C$, its roots are $\cos(2\pi/7), \cos(4\pi/7), \cos(6\pi/7)$, so the Galois group of the cubic is cyclic, and we know how it factors mod $p$ according to $p$ mod $7$ :

If $p \neq 7$, the cubic has $3$ roots mod $p$ iff $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 7$, and it has no root otherwise.

Moreover, $a^2-1 = \cos(2\pi/7)^2-1 = - \sin(2\pi/7)^2 = (i\sin(2\pi/7))^2$, so this has a square root $a'$ if and only if there is a $7$th root of unity $a+a' = \exp(2i\pi/7)$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Thus, the cubic splits and $a^2-1$ is a not square mod $p$ if and only if $p \equiv 6 \pmod 7$.

Comment: The thing you have to prove basically forces $\Bbb Q(a) = \Bbb Q(\cos(2\pi/7))$, and then *of course* it is common knowledge that $\cos^k(2\pi/7) + \cos^k(4\pi/7) + \cos^k(6\pi/7) = -1/2$ for $k=1,3,5$

Comment: Common to you, maybe, but not to me. Do you have a reference for these types of identities?

Comment: (it was sarcasm) you can show them the brute-force way by using $\cos x = \frac 12(\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix))$ and $\sum_{k=0}^6 \exp(2ik\pi/7)=0$. But more importantly I don't see how the first sentence is true so this is likely incomplete at best and wrong at worst

Comment: the first sentence is true but highly nonobvious : $ab+bc+ac = (3(a^5+b^5+c^5) + 2(a+b+c)^5 - 5(a+b+c)^2(a^3+b^3+c^3))/(5(a+b+c)^3 - 5(a^3+b^3+c^3))$  

 if I'm not mistaken